# Prisma cannot connect to MariaDB Docker instance

Tags: database, docker, networking, docker-compose, prisma

i'm running this docker-compose config, but i can't connect to the database for some reason.

```
services:
  db:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: "lscr.io/linuxserver/mariadb:latest"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "election"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pw"
    networks:
      election_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.0.2
  server:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: .
    networks:
      election_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.21.0.3
      public_services:
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  election_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.21.0.0/16
  public_services:
    external: true
```

i have a Node.JS backend running with express and prisma, but my prisma cannot connect to my database.

also for some reason when i set the enviroment variable, it says something along the lines of: DATABASE_URL value not found.

can anybody help me?
this is my schema.prisma:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = "mysql://root:pw@172.21.0.2:3306/election?schema=public"
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact actual error, and what part of the process produces it?  Manually specifying IP addresses isn't usually a recommended practice, but you should be able use the Compose service name `db` as a host name for connections between containers.  (Note that the database container _is_ publicly accessible via its `ports:`, and the `server` is not in spite of being on a "public" Docker-internal network.)